# Squash drops in a new comment each time... By design?

Tags: git

This is a question about `autosquash` which is a function of git. 
Discussion here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/autosquashing-git-commits

So in using `git commit --fixup` or `git commit --squash`, what I notice is that each time I use them, I get a new `squash!` or `fixup!` comment which means that my 3rd commit is 3 deep.

For example: `squash! squash! squash! ...other comments here...`

If I have 3 commits squashed.  It's not clear by the documentation if this is by design, i.e. some means for knowing what the order of the commits should be, or if I should allow only one. Also, if I enter `squash!` manually, without `--squash`, will this negatively affect `autosquash`?

In summary, should I allow only one `squash!` or `fixup!` per commit? Will manually entered `squash!` or `fixup!` negatively impact `autosquash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* intentional, but if your Git is earlier than 1.8.4, it does not work right.  From [`Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L157):

> - Having multiple `fixup!` on a line in the rebase instruction sheet
>     did not work very well with `git rebase -i --autosquash`.

Specifically, [commit 22c5b136363c7aa427667876e787db832548a038](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22c5b136363c7aa427667876e787db832548a038) added the code needed to handle these.

As for the actual order, it's done in the interactive rebase script, which tries pretty hard to preserve the initial topological order except for moving squash and/or fixup lines.  The overall script is up to almost 1300 lines of shell at this point and fairly impenetrable in places.  I *think* you'll be OK with manually inserted squash or fixup lines, but I cannot say for certain here.

Note that if you're building up a lot of pending squashes and fixups, it might be wise to run an interactive autosquash rebase and grind them out anyway, just for your own sanity. :-)

Comment: OK. Seems unnecessarily verbose though.  1. That seems like something that could be gotten pragmatically without involving the user.  2. Why not use a syntax like !Fixup:0...!Fixup:n instead with only one per commit?

Comment: I don't always agree with what are (or seem to be) the design decisions of the Git maintainers, I'm really guessing here based on the fact that they've had 10 releases in which to change it. :-) I probably would never have invented autosquash in the first place myself, though: if you want that sort of thing, it makes more sense to me to just commit, run rebase -i, rearrange, and go, so you'd never have more than "the last one" anyway.